# How to recommend deletion on a post outside the review queue

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-delete

I've been in this situation a couple of times before, but I usually just decided to flag the post for moderator attention, but I'm really wondering if there's any better way: if I see an answer that should be deleted in my opinion, for example a link-only answer, should I always flag it? The only thing I can think of that I could possibly do with that question is leave a comment, but that probably won't get it into the deletion queue. (and downvoting doesn't seem like it'd be the best solution either).

And if I should flag it, what should I flag link-only answers as? Running down the flag options: no, it's not spam, no it's not offensive, yes it is attempting to answer the question, no it does not have "***severe*** formatting or content problems", so the only remaining option would be entering a custom message.

So, tl;dr: if I would want to nominate an answer for deletion, what should I do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ask yourself:

> Is this post harmful to the site in some way that warrants moderator action?

If the answer is no, then move on.

If the answer is yes, then flag the post for moderator attention.  If you're uncertain about which type of moderator flag to use, then use a custom moderator flag, and explain the problem, answering the following questions:

1. Why is this harmful?
2. What do you want us to do about it?

Moderators act on posts where something bad is happening, and the community cannot handle it on their own.

Comment: That's the thing though: answers like link-only answers can be handled by the community perfectly fine. I just have no idea how to nominate a certain answer to get into the review queue for it.

Comment: Casting a delete vote or a downvote should put it into one of the review queues.  If you don't have delete vote privileges, cast a custom moderator flag, and explain the problem.

Comment: Yes, but the question is why can't we flag answers as link only outside of the review queue. If it is in the review queue, then you are given the option to recommend deletion, which raises a flag for a link only answer. You should be able to flag it as a link only answer, not have to do a custom moderator action and put text in there. I am sure a lot of people would like this.

Comment: @staticx: if it's *truly* a link-only answer, then it is "not an answer" and can be flagged as such. It will then get sent to the review queue where others can "recommend deletion".

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Then probably the text should be changed for Not An Answer. It mentions nothing about a link-only answer. The Review Queue is actually better in this regard... it says, "Does not attempt to answer the question..". Well the link does attempt to answer the question. It's just not a very good answer.